# Upload APK file to google play

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, apk

I tried to upload an APK file to Google Play and I received this error:

> You uploaded an APK signed with a certificate that expires too soon. You need to sign your APK with a certificate that expires farther into the future

Can you help me solve this problem?

```
keytool.exe -genkey -v -keystore release.keystore -alias TicTacToe -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Where can I find this code?

Comment: Easiest would be to search google for how to create a proper key for signing apps.

Comment: thanks u i will say in a few minutes if it help

Comment: keytool.exe -genkey -v -keystore release.keystore -alias TicTacToe -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000     **bold** where can i find this code?

Comment: You already found it. Now run it.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be greater than 50 year's! Use: -validity 20000